# How can I attach the latest Newman HTML report to Jenkins email while keeping previous reports in Newman folder?

Tags: newman

I want to attach latest newman html report to jenkins email.

But also i want to keep all my previous reports in newman folder.

Newman reports should not get updated everytime.

Could someone please help-

as of now my build in Jenkins looks like this

newman run --disable-unicode C:\Users\Raj\PostmanCollections\CheckHealthAPIs.postman_collection.json -e C:\Users\Raj\PostmanCollections\DEV.postman_environment.json -g C:\Users\Raj\PostmanCollections\workspace.postman_globals.json --bail false -n 1 --reporters cli,junit,htmlextra --reporter-junit-export "C:\Users\Raj.jenkins\workspace\PostmanAYSAPIs\Newman_Junit.xml" --reporter-htmlextra-export "C:\Users\Raj.jenkins\workspace\PostmanAYSAPIs\newman"

I have tried below code

newman run --disable-unicode C:\Users\Raj\PostmanCollections\CheckHealthAPIs.postman_collection.json -e C:\Users\Raj\PostmanCollections\DEV.postman_environment.json -g C:\Users\Raj\PostmanCollections\workspace.postman_globals.json --bail false -n 1 --reporters cli,junit,htmlextra --reporter-junit-export "C:\Users\Raj.jenkins\workspace\PostmanAYSAPIs\Newman_Junit.xml" --reporter-htmlextra-export "C:\Users\Raj.jenkins\workspace\PostmanAYSAPIs\newman\Nemman_report.html"

But report is getting updated everytime